# Pairwise bool and in c++ template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, partial-specialization

I am writing a template that takes a arbitrary number of arguments and find the Boolean AND on these value.

```
template <bool... Vs> struct meta_bool_and;

template <bool V> struct meta_bool_and : std::integral_constant<bool, V> {}; 

template <bool V, bool... Vs> 
struct meta_bool_and : std::integral_constant<bool, V && meta_bool_and<Vs...>::value> {};
```

However, I failed to compile by the following message

```
 error: redeclared with 2 template parameters
 struct meta_bool_and : std::integral_constant<bool, V && meta_bool_and<Vs...>::value> {};
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have written a re-definition instead of a partial specialization. In order to provide a specialization, you must specify what properties you specialize on.

This will work:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <bool... Vs> struct meta_bool_and;

template <bool V> struct meta_bool_and<V> : std::integral_constant<bool, V> {};
//                                    ^^^

template <bool V, bool... Vs> 
struct meta_bool_and<V, Vs...> : std::integral_constant<bool, V && meta_bool_and<Vs...>::value> {}; 
//                  ^^^^^^^^^^
```

As an improvement, think whether you want to support the empty conjunction (typically defined as true). If so, don't specialize on `meta_bool_and<bool>` but on `meta_bool_and<>` (derived from `std::true_type`).

Answer (score 8):

As alternatives, you may write it:

```
template <bool ... Bs>
using meta_bool_and = std::is_same<std::integer_sequence<bool, true, Bs...>,
                                   std::integer_sequence<bool, Bs..., true>>;
```

or in c++17:

```
template <bool ... Bs>
using meta_bool_and = std::integral_constant<bool, (Bs && ...)>;
```

Comment: The first one is very smart. Almost too smart for me…

Comment: `std::integral_sequence` ? Do you mean `std::integer_sequence` ?

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818:typo fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since these are specializations, they need to be declared as such. You can also make one the base case

```
template <bool V, bool... Vs>
struct meta_bool_and : std::integral_constant<bool, V && meta_bool_and<Vs...>::value> {};
// made base case

template <bool V>
struct meta_bool_and<V> : std::integral_constant<bool, V> {};
// specialization   ^^^
```