# How to detect if a type is one of a list of generic types

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming, enable-if

If I have

```
template <typename T> struct A;
template <typename T> struct B;
template <typename T> struct C;
template <typename T> struct D;
```

what is the most compact way of testing if some candidate type `X` is one of them? I'm looking for something like

```
boost::enable_if< is_instantiation_of_any<X,A,B,C,D> >
```

but A,B,C and D are templates so I'm not sure how to construct the above.

Comment: `X,A,B,C,D` is a list of templates, not a list of types. You want templates, right? (ie its rather a `std::is_instantiation_of_any` rather than `is_any`)

Comment: yes the name is a better fit.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing, is C++11 the max standard you're looking for? If not, I've posted an answer for C++14/17, and you could add another tag to the question.

Comment: Yes it's part of customer API and our limit is C++11 at the moment. It's still a useful answer so leave it there but the question has been answered also with a C++11 answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not sure if there exists a `std::is_instantiation_of`, though if all templates have same number of parameters, it is straightforward to implement it (if they don't it is more complicated). To check if a type is an instantiation of any of given templates you just need to fold it (requires C++17):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<type_traits>


template <typename T> struct A;
template <typename T> struct B;
template <typename T> struct C;
template <typename T> struct D;


template <typename T,template<typename> typename X>
struct is_instantiation_of : std::false_type {};

template <typename A,template<typename> typename X>
struct is_instantiation_of<X<A>,X> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T,template<typename> typename...X>
struct is_instantiation_of_any {
    static const bool value = ( ... || is_instantiation_of<T,X>::value);
};

int main(){
    std::cout << is_instantiation_of< A<int>, A>::value;
    std::cout << is_instantiation_of< A<double>, B>::value;
    std::cout << is_instantiation_of_any< A<int>,A,B>::value;
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/PPrf6P):

```
101
```

---

To get a C++11 compliant solution, we can use this neat trick from one of [Jarod42s answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37148692/4117728):

> ```
> template <bool ... Bs>
> using meta_bool_and = std::is_same<std::integer_sequence<bool, true, Bs...>,
>                                    std::integer_sequence<bool, Bs..., true>>;
> ```

Its rather clever, `true,a,b,c` and `a,b,c,true` are only the same when `a`, `b` and `c` are all `true`. `std::integer_sequence` is C++14, but all we need here is a type that has the bools as part of its definition:

```
namespace my {
    template <typename T,T ...t>
    struct integer_sequence {};
}
```

Using that we can rewrite the above to:

```
template <bool ... Bs>
using my_all = std::is_same<my::integer_sequence<bool, true, Bs...>,
                            my::integer_sequence<bool, Bs..., true>>;
```

And as `"ANY(a,b,c,d,...)"` is just `"! ALL( !a, !b, !c, !d,...)"` we can use:

```
template <bool ... Bs>
struct my_any { static constexpr bool value = ! my_all< ! Bs...>::value; };
```

to write `is_instantiation_of_any` in a C++11 friendly way:

```
template <typename T,template<typename> typename...X>
struct is_instantiation_of_any {
    static const bool value = my_any< is_instantiation_of<T,X>::value ...>::value;
};
```

[Complete C++11 example](https://godbolt.org/z/4n118P)

Comment: Now make it work for a template with arbitrary number of type and non-type arguments :D

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili please don't tease me, my break was already too long ;)

Comment: These template questions always snipe me too https://xkcd.com/356/

Comment: Tagged C++11, so fold expression should be replaced. (there is a [trick for `all_of`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37148692/2684539) to avoid recursion, `any_of` is just the negation of `none_of` (which is `all_of` with negated condition)).

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Made it work with abitrary number of type and non-type arguments. https://godbolt.org/z/rTqqca ( random insertion of ... till it worked :) )

Comment: I lie! It works with an abitrary number of type arguments. :( but not with non type arguments. I think that would require an exponential number of overloads ???

Comment: @bradgonesurfing it's not generic enough if it doesn't work with an arbitrary number of type and non-type parameters in an arbitrary order. (looks like you sniped yourself with that too)

Comment: @bradgonesurfing not sure how serious Ayxans comment was, the thing is that "arbitrary number of mixed type and non-type parameters" is not just x2 or x3 more complex than what I presented in my answer but its a whole different story.

Comment: C++ 17 adds auto keyword to templates so we can do perfect forwarding. https://godbolt.org/z/bsMxWe seems close to a solution but I can't quite nail it.

Comment: My mistake. auto is only for non-type parameters. It doesn't mean auto type and non type parameters

Answer (score 3):

With C++17 (or C++14 if you edit as per the comments), you can use [`boost::hana::any_of`](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/group__group-_searchable.html#ga5f7ff0125c448983e1b96c3ffb84f646) as a helper:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/hana/any_of.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/tuple.hpp>
#include <type_traits>

namespace hana = boost::hana;

template <typename T> struct A {};
template <typename T> struct B {};
template <typename T> struct C {};
template <typename T> struct D {};
template <typename T> struct N {};

template<typename T>
bool fun(T) {      // overload for non-templated arguments (templated arguments
    return false;  // are a better match for the overload below)
}

template<typename T, template<typename> typename X>
bool fun(X<T>) { // overload for templated arguments
    auto constexpr pred = [](auto x){ // remove constexpr for < c++17
        return std::is_same_v<decltype(x), X<T>>;
        // return std::is_same<decltype(x), X<T>>::value; // for < c++17
    };
    return hana::any_of(hana::tuple<A<T>, B<T>, C<T>, D<T>>{}, pred);
};

int main() {
    A<int> a{};
    N<int> b{};
    int x = 3; fun(x);
    std::cout << fun(a) << fun(b) << fun(x) << std::endl; // prints 100
}
```

Probably you want to use `std::decay_t` before passing things to `std::is_same_v`.

Comment: this is interesting, but if I understand correctly it fails for eg `int x; fun(x);`, no? In other words, it only works for types that are instantiations of a template with a single parameter

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818, yes it fails in that case. But if one wants to check if a variable is of a non template class (or of a specific instatiation of a template class), then `std::is_same_v` does the job, no?

Comment: yes `std::is_same_v` can help, but its part of the question as I understood it. OP wants to test any type `X` for being an instantiation of `A`,`B`,`C` or `D`

Comment: I don't know, the question reads _but A,B,C and D are templates_, so I thought that the OP wanted an equivalent of `std::is_same_v` which checks equality of the "outermost template" rather than that of the concrete types.

Comment: `X` is not necessarily a template

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818, oh, ok, I understand what you mean now. Well, it was quick. If it's correct :P

Comment: I meant `X` is not necessarily an instantiation of a template, but I think you know what I meant

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818, and in this case the function should always return `false`, as that `X` cannot be an instantiation of `A`/`B`/`C`/`D`, if it is not an instatiation of anything, right?

Comment: yep. I am not sure, but I think you only need to add one overload that returns `false`